# Is there any way to display 0 when an array is [""]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects, next.js

I have an object that I'm iterating over using Object.keys(myData).map

```
const data = Object.keys(myData);

const output = data.map(key => (

{myData[key].bad.length} //correctly shows 2 for "bad" on "Bravo", but will show 1 for "bad" on "Charlie" when the array is[""]

));
```

Data

```
{
  "Alpha": {
    "bad": ["0001-00"],
    "good": ["0002-00", "0003-00", "0004-00"],
    "percent": 10,
    "optionOne": true,
    "optionTwo": false
  },
  "Bravo": {
    "bad": ["0002-11", "0003-01"],
    "good": ["0002-14", "0005-06"],
    "percent": 75,
    "optionOne": true,
    "optionTwo": true
  },
  "Charlie": {
    "bad": [""],
    "good": ["0131-00", "0007-13", "0001-92"],
    "percent": 25,
    "optionOne": true,
    "optionTwo": false
  }
}
```

I have this to display how many items are in the array, but when they array is [""] it will display 1. Any suggestion on how I will be able to display 0 when there array is [""]?

I have all of my code working here: https://repl.it/repls/DapperHungryFraction

Comment: Why does your array contain an empty string? Why not return an empty array `[]` instead from the server? If you can't change that then do not rely on length because it seems to always have at least 1 element in the array.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/GoldNewArraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter the array before taking the length.

This filters out empty strings:

```
myData[key].bad.filter(x=> x !== "").length;
```

Comment: Your filtering is unnecessarily verbose, simply `filter(x => x)` does the trick, as the empty string evaluates to the boolean false

Comment: True, he didn't say he wanted to filter out every other falsy value though.  I have accidentally filtered out 0s enough times to be fine with a little verbosity